# Match column to another column containing array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have very junior question in python - i have a dataframe with a column containing some IDs and separate dataframe that contains 2 columns, out of which 1 is an array:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"some_id": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame([["A", [1, 2]], ["B", [3, 4]], ["C", [5]]], columns=['letter', 'some_ids'])
```

I want to add do df1 new column "letter' that for a given "some_id" will look up df2, check if this id is in df2['some_ids'] and return df2['letter']

I tried this:

```
df1['letter'] = df2[df1[some_id].isin(df2['some_ids')].letter
```

and get NaNs - any suggestion where I make mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Create dictionary with flatten nested lists in dict comprehension and then use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
d = {x: a for a,b in zip(df2['letter'], df2['some_ids']) for x in b}
df1['letter'] = df1['some_id'].map(d)
```

Or mapping by `Series` created by [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) with [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df1['letter'] = df1['some_id'].map(df2.explode('some_ids').set_index('some_ids')['letter'])
```

Or use left join with `rename` column:

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2.explode('some_ids').rename(columns={'some_ids':'some_id'}), how='left')
```

---

```
print (df1)
  some_id letter
0       1      A
1       2      A
2       3      B
3       4      B
4       5      C
```